# Does Azure Synapse Analytics Database designer do not support Delta format

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, data-lake, data-lakehouse

According to [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/concepts-lake-database)

> Currently, Delta format support for lake databases is not supported in
> Synapse Studio.

Does it means, at present database designer do not support the Delta format to visually create the lake database tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Documentaion you cannot create lake database tables using the DELTA Format directly.
[image]

As you can see from the above only **Delimited** & **Parquet** formats are available to visually create lake database tables.

- The current version of Delta Lake included with Azure Synapse has language support for Scala, PySpark, and .NET and is compatible with Linux Foundation Delta Lake.

Know more about [Delta Lake &Key features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-what-is-delta-lake)

I have reproduced to create Lake database using the Spark SQL
In synapse notebook.

**Step 1:** Create Lake database using the below
CREATE  DATABASE lakedatabase0202
[image]
[image]

**Step 2:** create table using from storage account

```
USE lakedatabase02;
CREATE  TABLE employee
USING delta
LOCATION  'abfss://<container>@<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/deltafiles';
```

**Step 3:** Describe database

```
DESCRIBE  DATABASE lakedatabase02
```

[image]

Using Spark SQL langauge in synapse notebooks you can create lake database tables with DELTA format.